# WordPress constant scope using define method

Tags: wordpress, plugins, scope, path, constants

I'm defining plugin path as a constant through constant define method as shown below.

```
define( 'MY_PLUGIN_DIR', untrailingslashit( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) ) );
```

It is accessible within plugin all files and themes. But when I call this constant in another plugin this constant becomes undefined.

How I can get this plugin constant in another plugin? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your problem is the order that wordpress is calling your plugins: the plugins that sets the constant is loaded after the one who calls it.

A better explanation of how to force your plugin be loaded first can be found [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-plugins-load-order#post-1385859). I'm putting here a quote of the part that matters:

> The order that plugins are loaded (as of WP 2.9.1 at least) is determined by the order of an array stored as "active_plugins" in the WP options table. Whenever a plugin is activated, it is added to this array, the array is sorted alphabetically by plugin name, and the array is saved to the DB.
>
> Fortunately, there is a convenient action hook, "activated_plugins", that is called after the active plugins array is saved to the DB. This allows you to manipulate the order of the plugins stored in this array after the array is initially saved.

You'll have to the following PHP code in the plugin who defines the constant, then deactivate and reactivate it (copied from the link I providaded above).

```
function this_plugin_first() {
    // ensure path to this file is via main wp plugin path
    $wp_path_to_this_file = preg_replace('/(.*)plugins\/(.*)$/', WP_PLUGIN_DIR."/$2", __FILE__);
    $this_plugin = plugin_basename(trim($wp_path_to_this_file));
    $active_plugins = get_option('active_plugins');
    $this_plugin_key = array_search($this_plugin, $active_plugins);
    if ($this_plugin_key) { // if it's 0 it's the first plugin already, no need to continue
        array_splice($active_plugins, $this_plugin_key, 1);
        array_unshift($active_plugins, $this_plugin);
        update_option('active_plugins', $active_plugins);
    }
}
add_action("activated_plugin", "this_plugin_first");
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It's worked for me. Really appreciate your effort and time.